# ArcGIS XY Plot Problems on ArcMap10.2.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2

I am trying to do something that is very simple, but am having significant problems accomplishing this. I have two types of datasets. One is a set of shapefiles for each state in the US that will create the geographical boundaries of census designated places. The other is a file that contains the latitude and longitude coordinates of certain store locations. It comes in standard Windows formats (csv, excel etc.) What I would like to do is to calculate the distance from the store to the nearest place border. However, I am having significant trouble with the store locations file:

Problem 1: Basic test of data accuracy, having the stores show up on a map.

- The data originally was in a comma delimited file. When I followed the standard instructions (File -> Add Data -> Add XY Data…) to input the X,Y coordinates, they never show up on the regional map that I have selected.
- They do show up when I choose a different template ( Conterminous United States as a template). However, they show up in the wrong location and as a single point.
- I checked the accuracy of the coordinated by using the “Go TO XY” tool. This time it takes me to the correct place, so all the point coordinates are accurate and the format is understood.
- I noticed that the XY tool changes my coordinates to a different format. For example, the degree symbol as well as NWES are included in the tool. Changing my data to this format still does not make it show up.
- I played around with changing the X and Y coordinates around to make sure that this is not a problem
- I read that excel is the preferred format for table files in ArcGIS, so I decided to change them to excel file. However, ArcGIS would not recognize the file. From reading around on the forums, I found that I need to download Excel 2007 driver. Now I can use Excel data, but I have the same issue. 
  -There are a lot of different coordinate systems to choose from, I played around with all the US based ones (I have US data) and have the same issue with all of them.
- When I wanted to just visually see the data on a map, I used ArcGIS Explorer, everything worked fine and was super easy. Not sure why this is so difficult in ArcMap10.2.2

Problem 2: Getting the store location data into the Near tool.

- The Near tool does not recognize the text/excel file in which the coordinates are in.
- There are several options for choosing which type of data to convert it too. However, here I am not really sure which one is correct. I tried layer and shape and neither of them worked. Due to problems in Part 1, I can’t be sure if any issues stem from incorrect file type.

This is an example of what my data looks like:

X   Y
-92.26960754    30.34570885
-92.25918579    30.37543678
-92.26924133    30.33198738

These are the census shapefiles I am using (2010 Census):
https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_place.html

Any advice? I am quite new to ArcGIS. The online instructions seem really simple, but I am just not getting the results I want.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method for your problem 1, creating an xy event layer in ArcMap.

1. Open blank map document
2. Right click on Layers Data frame, select coordinate system tab, and set the CRS to match xy coordinates in table (in your case set to WGS 1984, EPSG 4326
3. Add table to map, right click table and select the display XY option (may not be the exact name) (you may also define the event layer CRS here too)
4. Add in control layer that you know is projected correctly to compare against xy event layer
5. Finally, right click xy event layer and select Data>Export option to create GIS layer (e.g. shapefile, or geodatabase feature class...etc)

Once you have the new layer, I would recommend re-projecting (using the Project tool) the layer from a geographic coordinate system to a projected coordinate system so when you run the Near tool your result will be in feet or meters rather than decimal degrees.  For a more in-depth discussion on projections see link below:

[What are map projections?](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//003r00000001000000)